# How to calculate similarity between Chamber of Commerce numbers?

Tags: java, mysql, similarity

I am working on an engine that does OCR post-processing, and currently I have a set of organizations in the database, including Chamber of Commerce Numbers.

Also from the OCR output I have a list of possible Chamber of Commerce (COC) numbers.

What would be the best way to search the most similar one? Currently I am using Levenshtein Distance, but the result range is simply too big and on big databases I really doubt it's feasibility. Currently it's implemented in Java, and the database is a MySQL database.

Side note: A Chamber of Commerce number in The Netherlands is defined to be an 8-digit number for every company, an earlier version of this system used another 4 digits (0000, 0001, etc.) to indicate an establishment of an organization, nowadays totally new COC numbers are being given out for those.

Example of COCNumbers:

- 30209227
- 02045251
- 04087614
- 01155720
- 20081288
- 020179310000
- 09053023
- 09103292
- 30039925
- 13041611
- 01133910
- 09063023
- 34182B01
- 27124701

List of possible COCNumbers determined by post-processing:

- 102537177
- 000450093333
- 465111338098
- NL90223l30416l
- NLﬂ0737D447B01
- 12juni2013
- IBANNL32ABNA0242244777
- lncassantNL90223l30416l10000
- KvK13041611
- BtwNLﬂ0737D447B01

A few extra notes:

- The post-processing picks up words and word groups from the invoice, and those word groups are being concatenated in one string. (A word group is at it says, a group of words, usually denoted by a space between them).
- The condition that the post-processing uses for it to be a COC number is the following: The length should be 8 or more, half of the content should be numbers and it should be alphanumerical.
- The amount of possible COCNumbers determined by post-processing is relatively small.
- The database itself can grow very big, up to 10.000s of records.

How would I proceed to find the best match in general? (In this case (13041611, KvK13041611) is the best (and moreover correct) match)

Comment: did you implement ocr? if yes, can you exclude candidates which contains non numeric characters? As i don think levenshtein distance is right way to go, as difference between l8 and 18 is same as from 28

Comment: I did not implement the OCR itself, only post-processing. But I can exclude candicates which have no non-numeric characters, however they may be correct as "KvK 13 04 16 11" got concatened to "KvK13041611". And I am indeed currently doubting if levenshtein distance is the way to go.

Comment: Follow up: Levenshtein Distance might actually still work if and only if the length of str1 and str2 are the same. However it still could be a pain for a big amount of records.

Comment: Do these numbers have a check digit?  It would be very helpful to your accuracy if they do.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this matching exclusively in MySQL is probably a bad idea for a simple reason: there's no way to use a regular expression to modify a string natively.

You're going to need to use some sort of scoring algorithm to get this right, in my experience (which comes from ISBNs and other book-identifying data).

This is procedural -- you probably need to do it in Java (or some other procedural programming language).

1. Is the candidate string found in the table exactly?  If yes, score 1.0.
2. Is the candidate string "kvk" (case-insensitive) prepended to a number that's found in the table exactly? If so, score 1.0.
3. Is the candidate string the correct length, and does it match after changing lower case L into 1 and upper case O into 0?  If so, score 0.9
4. Is the candidate string the correct length after trimming all alphabetic characters from either beginning or the end, and does it match? If so, score 0.8.
5. Do both steps 3 and 4, and if you get a match score 0.7.
6. Trim alpha characters from both the beginning and end, and if you get a match score 0.6.
7. Do steps 3 and 6, and if you get a match score 0.55.
8. The highest scoring match wins.
9. Take a visual look at the ones that don't match after this set of steps and see if you can discern another pattern of OCR junk or concatenated junk. Perhaps your OCR is seeing "g" where the input is "8", or other possible issues.

You may be able to try using Levenshtein's distance to process these remaining items if you match substrings of equal length.  They may also be few enough in number that you can correct your data manually and proceed.

Another possibility: you may be able to use Amazon Mechanical Turk to purchase crowdsourced labor to resolve some difficult cases.